# Policy classes with differing interfaces

Tags: c++, c++11, policy-based-design

Suppose an algorithm that has a policy `FooPolicy`. Policy classes that implement this policy feature a static member function `foo`, but, for some of them, `foo` takes an `int` argument, while for others it does not. I am trying to enable the use of these policy classes with differing interfaces by means of `constexpr` static data members:

```
struct SimpleFoo {
    static constexpr bool paramFlag = false;
    static void foo() {
        std::cout << "In SimpleFoo" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct ParamFoo {
    static constexpr bool paramFlag = true;
    static void foo(int param) {
        std::cout << "In ParamFoo " << param << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename FooPolicy>
struct Alg {
    void foo() {
        if (FooPolicy::paramFlag) FooPolicy::foo(5);
        else FooPolicy::foo();
    }
};

int main() {
    Alg<ParamFoo> alg;
    alg.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile. `gcc 4.8.2` gives the error:

> no matching function for call to ‘ParamFoo::foo()’
>
> else FooPolicy::foo();

The `else` clause gets compiled despite the fact that it is known at compile time that `FooPolicy::paramFlag` is `true`. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Yes, provide two overloads which are conditionally selected via e.g. tag dispatching

Comment: You can even dispense with the flag and just SFINAE it.

Comment: You cannot agree on an `int param = 0` parameter for all functions?

Comment: A different approach is to use objects, not types, in the way the standard library does for its policies (comparators, hashers, allocators). Then those objects can be stateful.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's difficult to see what you mean from a short comment like this. How does using objects take care of the fact that the two policies have different interfaces? I would very much appreciate if you turn your comment into a reply.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg: You give every policy the same interface, but make the "argument" part of the state: `X<Policy1> x;` vs `X<Policy2> y(Policy2(5))`. Just like stateful allocators, if that makes sense.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think I understand the idea. The problem with this design is that the user of `X` does not know in advance the value of the argument that `X::foo` will need to pass to the policy (5 in the example). In fact, `X::foo` may need to call `Policy2::foo` many a time with different values of the argument (i.e. different states)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Is there a way to make it work?*

One solution is to use tag-dispatching:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename FooPolicy>
struct Alg {
    void foo() {
        foo(std::integral_constant<bool, FooPolicy::paramFlag>{});
    }    
private:
    void foo(std::true_type) {
        FooPolicy::foo(5);
    }
    void foo(std::false_type) {
        FooPolicy::foo();
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d80f535fb9a19e1e)

Answer (score 3):

You could dispense with the flag entirely and use expression SFINAE:

```
template <typename FooPolicy>
struct Alg {
    template <typename T=FooPolicy> //put FooPolicy in immediate context
    //SFINAEd out if that call is not valid
    auto foo() -> decltype(T::foo(),void()) {
        FooPolicy::foo();
    }

    template <typename T=FooPolicy>
    auto foo() -> decltype(T::foo(0),void()) {
        FooPolicy::foo(6);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a better design!