# Decoupling host and policy classes at the cost of stateful policy classes and not following Item 26 of Effective C++

Tags: c++, policy-based-design

This post consists of describing a problem with the straightforward implementation of the policy-based design, proposing an alternative implementation, analyzing the proposed implementation and asking help in giving correct weight to the different factors in the analysis. I apologize for the length of the post and hope that you will stick with me.

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

Suppose that we use policy-based design as follows:

```
template <typename FooPolicy> 
struct Alg {
    void operator()() {
        ...
        FooPolicy::foo(arguments);
        ...
    }
};
```

There is a degree of *coupling* between the above host class and the policy: if the signature of `FooPolicy::foo` changes, then the code in `Alg::operator()` has to change accordingly.

The coupling becomes much tighter if policy classes are given a degree of freedom for choosing an interface. For example, suppose that `FooPolicy` may implement either `foo` without parameters or `foo` with one integer parameter (the implementation for this case was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32604926/2725810)):

```
template <typename FooPolicy> struct Alg {
    void operator()() {
        int arg = 5; // any computation can be here
        // using tag dispatch to call the correct `foo`
        foo(std::integral_constant<bool, FooPolicy::paramFlag>{}, arg);
    }

private:
    void foo(std::true_type, int param) { FooPolicy::foo(param); }
    void foo(std::false_type, int param) {
        (void)param;
        FooPolicy::foo();
    }
};

struct SimpleFoo {
    static constexpr bool paramFlag = false;
    static void foo();
};

struct ParamFoo {
    static constexpr bool paramFlag = true;
    static void foo(int param);
};
```

Obviously, whenever one adds a policy class with a different interface, he will have to update the dispatching mechanism, which can become complicated.

**PROPOSED DESIGN**

I am considering a design, whereby the algorithm would provide an interface that function members of the policy class can use to get data instead of accepting arguments. For the above example, it might look as follows:

```
// The policy-independent part of Alg factored out
struct AlgPolicyIndependent {
    int getArg() const { return arg; }
protected:
    int arg;
};

// The interface to be used by FooPolicy
struct FooPolicyServices {
    FooPolicyServices(const AlgPolicyIndependent &myAlg) : alg(myAlg) {};
    int getArg() const { return alg.getArg(); }
private:
    const AlgPolicyIndependent &alg;
};

template <typename FooPolicy>
struct Alg : private AlgPolicyIndependent {
    Alg() : fooPolicy(FooPolicyServices(*this)) {};
    void operator()() {
        arg = 5; // any computation can be here
        fooPolicy.foo();
    }
private:
    FooPolicy fooPolicy;
};

struct SimpleFoo {
    SimpleFoo(const FooPolicyServices &myS) : s(myS) {};
    void foo() { std::cout << "In SimpleFoo" << std::endl; }
private:
    const FooPolicyServices &s;
};

struct ParamFoo {
    ParamFoo(const FooPolicyServices &myS) : s(myS) {};
    void foo() { std::cout << "In ParamFoo " << s.getArg() << std::endl; }
private:
    const FooPolicyServices &s;
};
```

**ANALYSIS**

With this design, a policy is free to use any data obtainable by using the public interface of the corresponding `Services` class. In our example, `ParamFoo::foo` got the algorithm's `arg` by using `FooPolicyServices::getArg`. The host class simply calls `FooPolicy::foo` without arguments and this will not have to change even if `FooPolicy::foo` changes, which is the *decoupling* we wanted.

I see two disadvantages to this design:

1. `arg` has become part of the state of `Alg` instead of being a local variable in `Alg::operator()`, which goes against **Item 26** of **Effective C++** saying that variables should be defined as late as possible. However, the reasoning of that item does not apply if the cost of the extra initialization of `arg` is negligible compared to the cost of running the algorithm.
2. Policy classes have gotten a state. So, we cannot use policies by simply calling their static member functions.

**QUESTIONS**

Three questions:

1. Is the decoupling achieved by the proposed design worth the two disadvantages listed above?
2. Are there disadvantages that I overlooked?
3. Does the proposed design have a name?

---

Based on the reply by @Useless, here is an updated implementation. This implementation makes it possible to have stateless policy classes, but has an overhead of passing the same reference to a `Services` object each time a policy is used.

```
// The policy-independent part of Alg
struct AlgPolicyIndependent {
    int getArg() const { return arg; }
protected:
    int arg;
};

// The interface to be used by FooPolicy
struct FooPolicyServices {
    FooPolicyServices(const AlgPolicyIndependent &myAlg) : alg(myAlg) {};
    int getArg() const { return alg.getArg(); }
private:
    const AlgPolicyIndependent &alg;
};

template <typename FooPolicy>
struct Alg : private AlgPolicyIndependent {
    Alg() : fooPolicyServices(*this) {};
    void operator()() {
        arg = 5; // any computation can be here
        FooPolicy::foo(fooPolicyServices);
    }
private:
    FooPolicyServices fooPolicyServices;
};

struct SimpleFoo {
    static void foo(const FooPolicyServices &s) {
        (void)s;
        std::cout << "In SimpleFoo" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct ParamFoo {
    static void foo(const FooPolicyServices &s) {
        std::cout << "In ParamFoo " << s.getArg() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: BTW, this feels like it a better fit for Programmers.SE - if you decide to move or (or it gets flagged), let me know and I'll copy my answer over too.

Comment: @Useless when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat - Good point! OP, I was suggesting the possibility of migration, not a cross-post.

Answer (score 1):

> There is a degree of coupling between the above host class and the policy

### Or, "Is the coupling inherent in the Policy pattern a problem"?

No. There is an equivalent degree of coupling between each of the algo and the policy, and the *interface*, which one requires and the other implements.

Consider the runtime-polymorphic equivalent, the Strategy:

```
struct IStrategy {
    virtual ~IStrategy() {}
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
struct FooStrategy: public IStrategy {
    void foo() override;
}
void algo(IStrategy *s) {
    // ...
    s->foo();
}
```

Now, there is *exactly* the same degree of coupling between the concrete strategy and the algorithm function on the (explicit base-class) interface in the Strategy pattern, as there is between the policy and algorithm template on the (implicit duck-typed) interface in the Policy pattern.

I'm not suggesting this coupling doesn't exist, but I am pointing out that this degree of coupling is not usually considered excessive.

Note there's an exact run-time analogy for your variation too - optionally implementing other (and more specific) interfaces, and using `dynamic_cast` to investigate at run-time which are supported.

---

### Questions

1. > Is the decoupling ... worth the two disadvantages listed above?

   Maybe! It depends how troublesome the coupling has become in practice,  and how much state is being passed around.

   In any case ...
2. > Are there disadvantages that I overlooked?

   There are plenty of disadvantages to statefulness in general, and your suggested design in particular:

   - global (ie, non-local-scope) state interacts badly with concurrency (use the same algorithm object from multiple threads and everything breaks)
   - it interacts badly with re-entrant use (accidentally use the same algorithm object from *inside* its own Policy call, and everything breaks)
   - if you want to re-use a stateful object, you may need to provide an additional method to reset its state
   - you then have to *remember to call* that method *everywhere* the object could be reused
   - the two points above are essentially a bad, manual, error-prone emulation of just using local-scope state in the first place
   - in addition to writing that extra code, you also made your object bigger, to store state you don't really want outside the method scope anyway
   - in your particular case, you also made the policy bigger (to store a pointer back to your state) *and* every policy call now has an extra indirection in the pointer chase `this->services->value` to get an argument

   While these *are* problems, they're also completely avoidable here. Just pass a local-scope context object to the policy method on every call. Then:

   - there's no requirement for the algo object to be stateful at all, because the context object has local scope in the method
   - there's no need for the policy to be stateful either, because the context can simply be passed as the only argument on each call

   note that in your edit, the algorithm is still stateful. However, the services/independent things (what I called the context) can just be a local variable in the algorithm method. There's no need to preserve it outside that method, and replacing the data member with a local makes the algo stateless.
3. > Does the proposed design have a name?

   It looks like the Context pattern to me. The original suggestion looks like a sort of uncomfortable home-rolled dependency injection, but I'd stick with stateless policy & algorithm, and pass the working state around in a Context object for preference.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please clarify your answer: First, I did not understand the subject of the part of the answer before you talk about the specific items (1-3).  Second, could you please explain: when is statefulness a problem? (I sensed it could be the case, but cannot pinpoint the exact reason). As for your suggestion, since the algorithm is part of a generic library, I want to avoid any overhead, even as small as passing a pointer.

Comment: Thirdly, in your suggestion you're _already_ passing a pointer from the stateful algo to the stateful policy: the policy depends on it's `this` pointer to follow another pointer or reference to the services object. Since the optimizer can inline the policy method and elide any unused `this` argument, you just added an indirection _and_ made both the algo and policy objects bigger: this is more overhead than is notionally saved by avoiding the context argument.

Comment: Please see the version based on your reply at the bottom of my post and the comment that introduces it.  As for the terminology, that no one talks about coupling does not mean there is none, does it?

Comment: Do you mean the *Encapsulate Context Pattern* (http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/overload63-FINAL.pdf)?

Comment: That (and much of the IMO misguided discussion on the Pattern Wiki) concerns encapsulating _global_ context. We're talking about encapsulating _local_ context. IIRC the GoF Design Patterns book uses Context in this sense (I don't have a copy to hand).

Comment: I did not find a pattern named *Context* in Gamma et al. The main point of the paper I cited was to avoid long parameter lists by using *context objects* instead. This seems to be precisely the mechanism I am using here, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes agreed, whatever you call it (if there even is an agreed pattern name).